# Babel standard family and .otf font features

Tags: babel, opentype

Compiling this simple code to apply a particular Style Set locally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{EBGaramond}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature={+calt,+ss06}]{EBGaramond}

\begin{document}

Q \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}

\myfont{Q  \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}}

\end{document}
```

I receive:

```
Package babel Info: The current font is not a babel standard family:
(babel)             EBGaramond:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+pnum;+onum;
+calt,+ss06;
(babel)             There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this warning, and

(babel)             you can ignore it altogether if you do not need these
(babel)             families. But if they are used in the document, you should 
be
(babel)             aware 'babel' will no set Script and Language for them, so
(babel)             you may consider defining a new family with \babelfont.
```

How should I correct `\newfontfamily`?

Thank you

Comment: The message explain what to do: “you may consider defining a new family with \babelfont“. It also explains that “There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this warning“. If the result is fine, then your settings are also fine.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can switch to the standard font and add the font feature.  You seem to want the command to change the text within brackets, but what the `\myfont` command actually does is change the font to EB Garamond stylistic set 6 from that point on.  So, here is a demo of how to do it three different ways:

- A `\textswash` command, like `\textsc` or `\textsf`
- A `\swashstyle` command, like `\scshape` or `\sffamily`
- Commands `\Qswash` for a capital sqashed Q and `\qswash` for a small-caps swashed Q

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{EBGaramond}
\newcommand\swashstyle{\rmfamily\addfontfeature{StylisticSet=6}}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textswash{\swashstyle}
\newcommand\Qswash{\textswash{Q}}
\newcommand\qswash{\textswash{\scshape q}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Q \textsc{Q} \textsc{q} \\
\textswash{Q  \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}} \\
\Qswash \textsc{\Qswash} \qswash \\
{\swashstyle Q \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}}

\end{document}
```

You could also ignore the warning.  Like the message says, it’s harmless.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: looking at p. 25-26 of babel's documentation, I've found this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{EB Garamond}
\babelfont{myfont}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature={+calt,+ss06}]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

Q \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}

\textmyfont{Q} {\myfontfamily \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}}

\end{document}
```

Another way: use `polyglossia` instead of `babel`. Then, use `\addfontfeature` to activate the `+ss06` feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature={+calt}]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

Q \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}

{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+ss06} Q  \textsc{Q} \textsc{q}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In fact I used EB Garamond because it is a free font, but I need the code to activate other SS in another font. In this case various and more numerous forms of Cyrillic glyphs, so I thought that defining a font was more convenient than redefining several glyphs ... I don't find, in babel manual, how define a new font which is the same, but only with a different feature :(

Comment: @user41063 In my first example I defined twice the same font, with different features. I guess you can do the same with another opentype font, defining different names. Or am I not understanding your issue? By the way, I've no experience with babel. Also `\addfontfeature` of my 2nd example may be of use (you could define shorthands). I don't know if it's compatible with babel, but perhaps you can switch to polyglossia...

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I didn't realize that the correct string is ```\textmyfont```, not ```\myfont```. Moreover, there was an error in the lookuo. Now all works fine, thank you